Finding specific value in a list in java using a scanning loop: returns numberformat exception
I am trying to find a specific string in a text file.
Here is what I have using [Java] Lists:
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class constantb {
    static String filePath = "C:myiflepath";

    public static Double findDouble(String name) throws IOException{
        String value;
        Scanner constScanner = new Scanner(filePath);
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        while(constScanner.hasNextLine()){
            list.add(constScanner.nextLine()); 
        }
        value = list.get(list.indexOf(name)+1);
        System.out.println(value);
        constScanner.close();
        return Double.parseDouble(value);
    }
}

When I run this I get a NumberFormatException problem.
In the text file it searches for a name and right below that name in the file is what I want to return as a double.
Here is the text file:
help please:
double hi
9

I have tried removing the list part of the file:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class constantc{

    static String filePath = "C:myfilepath";

    public static Double findDouble(String name){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filePath);
        String value = scanner.nextLine();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            value = scanner.nextLine();
            if(name == scanner.nextLine()){
                scanner.nextLine();
                value = scanner.nextLine();
                break;
            }else{
                scanner.nextLine();
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        return Double.parseDouble(value);
    }
}

That did not work because I got the same error.

What is the "name" in help please: double hi 9?

Basic problem: You're calling scanner.nextLine() many times inside the loop, but each time it will advance to the next line. You should be checking value, not scanner.nextLine() in your if statements

Method parseDouble is throwing NumberFormatException because you are not extracting the correct value from the file. The file has more than three lines, correct? [Edit] your question and post a proper sample file. Then post an example name that you want to search for as well as the result you want to get if the name is found.

You aren't scanning the file, you are scanning the string literal "C:myiflepath".
You need to create a file handle and scan that.
Make a minor change to your first code sample as follows:
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class constantb {
    static String filePath = "C:myiflepath";
public static Double findDouble(String name) throws IOException{
    String value;
    File file = new File(filePath); // added 
    Scanner constScanner = new Scanner(file); // changed
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    while(constScanner.hasNextLine()){
        list.add(constScanner.nextLine()); 
    }
    value = list.get(list.indexOf(name)+1);
    System.out.println(value);
    constScanner.close();
    return Double.parseDouble(value);
}

}
Running your code in debug with a breakpoint at the start and stepping though and inspecting values would have allowed you to solve this easily.
